# Oracle : Create Table as Select statement and Select query on created table in Single Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle

I want Stored Procedure which create Temporary table using Create Table ... Select ... Statement.
And then select the records from same created table.
And finally drop that created table...

I want all these functionality in same stored procedure.

I have create the following stored procedure. But i got the below error

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

This one is my Procedure

```
DECLARE
TEMP_TBL VARCHAR2(4000);
TBL_NAME VARCHAR2(200) := 'ABC_TEST';

BEGIN
TEMP_TBL := 'CREATE TABLE MY_TAB_COL AS(SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,to_lob(DATA_DEFAULT) AS DATA_DEFAULT,NULLABLE FROM ALL_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME=''' || TBL_NAME || ''')';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TEMP_TBL);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE TEMP_TBL;

FOR DD_COLUMNS IN
(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM MY_TAB_COL)
LOOP 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DD_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME');

END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: This can not work. Are migrating something from MS SQL? PL/SQL is compiled language (like Java for example). So at the moment when this PL/SQL block is being compiled it is known that id depends on table named MY_TAB_COL.

Comment: You really, really don't want to create and drop a table in a procedure.  That will totally fail if you ever have multiple users running the code simultaneously.  If you are coming from another database (like SQL Server) where it's common to create local temporary tables, you really want to adapt to the Oracle conventions.  Just like it doesn't make sense to write Oracle-style code in SQL Server, it doesn't make sense to write SQL Server-style code in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want scenario like that, and not reccomend to use this code in production. I'm pretty sure in the 99% of the cases, this approach can be written in other way. But you can try the code bellow(Everything in your procedure should use dynamic sql)

```
declare
   TBL_NAME varchar2(200) := 'ABC_TEST';

   lv_Sql varchar2(4000);

begin
   lv_Sql := 'CREATE TABLE MY_TAB_COL AS(SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,to_lob(DATA_DEFAULT) AS DATA_DEFAULT,NULLABLE FROM ALL_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME=''' ||
             TBL_NAME || ''')';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_Sql);
   execute immediate lv_Sql;

   lv_Sql := 'begin
                 for DD_COLUMNS in (select TABLE_NAME from MY_TAB_COL) loop
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DD_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME);   
                 end loop;
              end;';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_Sql);
   execute immediate lv_Sql;

   for R in (select *
               from user_objects
              where object_name = 'MY_TAB_COL'
                and object_type = 'TABLE') loop
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('drop table ' || R.Object_Name);
      execute immediate 'drop table ' || R.Object_Name;
   end loop;
end;
```